# Why would a plane displaced with Geometry Nodes not appear displaced in Cycles Rendered View but does in EEVEE?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes

I'm experimenting with Geometry Nodes after following the Entagma "Alien Orb" tutorial on YouTube. I'd like to develop a general method for creating complex procedural cavities on arbitrary shapes. I'm starting with a simple case - cones in a plane.

I'm getting a funny issue that the displacement is visible in the Solid viewport shading and the Material Preview viewport shading and in EEVEE Rendered View. But the plane is entirely flat in Cycles Rendered view. Unfortunately, I plan to use Cycles so this is a problem. I've spent the day trying to figure out what is happening and I have come up empty-handed. I suspect it is something basic. I'd like to understand so I can keep the problem from happening in the future.

Here is the appearance of the displaced plane in Material Preview. Surface color is mapped to z of the Object Coordinates, so the shader is aware of the vertical displacement I've created.

[image: Material Preview of displaced plane]

Here is the appearance of the displaced plane in Cycles Rendered View. The shader hasn't changed, so it thinks the plane is not displaced (z = 0 = red everywhere). The outline of the displaced plane is visible in Rendered View.

[image: Rendered Preview of displaced plane]

[image]

Comment: Entagma. Good choice. :) I'm sorry to say,  [I can't reproduce this](https://imgur.com/a/f7ORVeW), in Blender 3.0a, 2021-06-24, on Linux, Nvidia. Does it work at lower subdiv. levels? Check graphics drivers? Maybe wait to see if others can reproduce.. if this is reportable, you want to make the report as useful as possible.

Comment: I get the same error as OP on Blender 2.93 (reproduceable). Also interesting to note that the displacement is still seen correctly in Solid View too!

Comment: Maybe fixed in 3.0a, then.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I've been thinking of moving to 3.0a. This seems to clinch it.

Comment: I just went back to my original follow-through of the Alien Orb. When I worked through the tutorial step-by-step I did not have the problem with the Cycle's Render View. The displaced icosphere reacted to light and the surface rendered as expected.

Comment: Based on Robin's feedback, I opened my blend file in Blender 3.0a. The Rendered View works correctly. Seems to be a bug in 2.93.